# Redirect to Index Not working on form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have several create pages.  The data is inserted properly into the database upon clicking my submit button.  However, the page just stays on my create.  It does not redirect to my Index, like I want it to.  I am able to redirect when I edit or delete records.

I've tried to these, with similar results:

```
return View("Index");
```

and

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Here is my current controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = from r in _db.Clients
                    orderby r.CompanyName ascending
                    select r;
        return View(model);
    }

public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Clients client)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Clients.Add(client);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index")
    }
```

I just have a simple button in my view.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-satgreen" value="Create"/>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is the way to go

Comment: I had that at one point, but again, it still does not redirect my view.  The data is still getting entered.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me :). So I will risk posting an incomplete answer here..
  As a common practice, when you have a form to submit, you should use @using (Html.BeginForm()). This will take care of all the technicalities of having a form and avoid unnecessary errors (which I can't identify in your code, sorry!!).
  Also, you can try putting a breakpoint at the Create action to see if it gets called properly.

Comment: I am using that.  My breakpoint hits the create action.  I said that it is posting my data correctly.

Comment: At the return RedirectToAction("Index"), did you check to see if it hits the Index action?

Comment: Yes it hits it, then just exits the method...I can't step into it though.

Comment: So, when you press F11 at return RedirectToAction("Index"), you can step into the Index action? Then what happens? It can't just suddenly exit the method..

Comment: It hits the closing "}" then exits.

Comment: You mean the closing "}" of the Create action? Is your Index action in the same controller? If not, you have to specify the path in the RedirectToAction call

Comment: Yes the closing "}" in the Create action.  The Index action is directly above my create action.  See edit above.

Comment: Please change the return View ("Index") to return RedirectToAction("Index") and try stepping into the Index action (by pressing F11 or putting a breakpoint at Index action). Also, you do have an Index view, right?

Comment: Yes I have an View index.  I have return RedirectToAction("Index") in my code, i just updated it above.  When the breakpoint is on return RedirectToAction("Index"); and I hit F11, it goes to the last "}" and then exits the method.

Comment: You are not placing them in the correct order. The return RedirectToAction should be above, the return View below. If that doesn't work, I've run out of ideas :(

Comment: Thanks but no luck.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I figured it out...there is an issue in my view.  I stripped out all of the html except what was necessary and it returned.  Thanks.

Comment: @C.Coggins, Why have you accepted this answer if it does not solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to redirect is to return RedirectResult.

In your case it seems to be:

```
[HttpGet]    
public ActionResult Create(Clients client)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Clients.Add(client);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return new RedirectResult("Index");
    }
```

Update:

To allow redirection you should use HTTP GET instead of POST. Add FormMethod.Get to your form parameters and change the attribute:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Get))
{
    // ...

    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still stays on the page, with the data being submitted.

Comment: I missed that it's HTTP Post. Will update my answer.